# ColdFusion formatting lost in emails

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I'm sending email with ColdFusion's `<cfmail>` tag. Most of it is working just fine.  However, I am sending through a formatted report which is misaligning the subtotals.  I have put the `text-align:right` specifically in the code:

```
<td class = "repcolrow" 
    style = "text-align: right;
             vertical-align:top;
             padding-top: 10px 
             color:##630D85 " >
        <a class = "repbordtop"
           style = "position:relative; top:4px; text-align: right">                      
            #formq#                  
        </a>
</td>
```

but after emailing I'm getting `text-align:left`.  The report as it appears before sending through email is correct:

[image: correctly formatted report]

The report as it appears after being emailed:

[image: misaligned totals]

Since the `text-align: right` is specifically in the code, it is hard to understand why it is aligning left after going through the email.  I have checked all the classes referenced, and none of them include any `text-align`.  I need the `<a` references to get the formatting right on the the actual number (`#formq#`).

Does anyone have a suggestion about where I could look to find the cause of the `text-align: left`?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are using? Which Email client are you using?

Comment: Formatting emails is notoriously problematic, and rendering differs between email clients. Assuming you’ve looked at the source code that is delivered with the email and it is correct, there’s not much you can do except change your html output to make it work using different html/css. Search google for “email html boilerplate” and you’ll find lots of articles and examples on the subject.

Comment: @Redtopia hit it on the nose. I worked at this one company and they turned 3 of us loose on 3 email clients. GMail, Outlook, and MacOS mail. PDF attachments were considered too. And then they wanted to then come up with something that would work on on three. In the end we had mostly pre-CSS HTML

Comment: James -- version 11 and gmail.

Comment: Redtopia and James.  I tried to look at the source code delivered with the email but couldn't see anything I could decipher.  Can you tell me what to look at?  I'll follow your suggestions about finding email html boilerplate , thanks.

Comment: There is definitely some black magic to email formatting but you can usually get what you want or at least close to it. My comment is that you keep mentioning it is text-align left instead of right. That may not be the case even though it looks that way. A couple of thoughts come to mind from what I see. Is that "Amount Paid" actually two table columns? If so, it could be that the line items have a `col-span=2` where the sub totals do not. My other thought is to turn on borders for the table to debug this. That will show you exactly where each cell is and might reveal the problem here.

Comment: Missing a semi-colon after "10px" in the first style attribute.

Comment: Miguel F -- a good thought about the cells, but I did indeed test it with visible borders, and it is not a problem of separate cells.

Comment: Scott -- you are quite right, and I fixed it, but it made no difference.

Comment: James and Redtopia, between yesterday and today all -- that is 100% all -- the formatting disappeared in the email versions.  The style statements are still there in the document.  I wonder if gmail has "improved" my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Coldfusion at all. It will send whatever you tell it to, but the mail client is free to ignore it-and they all do.

Every mail client is different, but the following is true pretty much across the board: only a very small subset of css styling is available; no css positioning works.

If you want to make good looking emails, you need to code like you live in the late 90s with HTML4. If you want layouts, they need to be table-based. `<font>` tags are more reliable than css. The css you can use needs to all be inline. It's not pretty, but there is no alternative.

(This is especially true in web-based clients like GMail, because if they let emails mess with positioning, it would probably be possible for an email to put bits of the email over parts of the GMail UI. In a client like Outlook, you can look at the raw source of the email to know what was sent to you, even if it won't display it all, but GMail will strip anything unsupported right out.)

Comment: This is helpful, and I will consider whether it is worth putting my formatting inline, or just letting it go through whatever way it goes.  It is peculiar that gmail originally received my emails pretty much as formatted, and then suddenty went to no formatting at all.